# Fedora 25 : libgcc_s.so.1 not found

Tags: android, linux, fedora-25

I am using Fedora25 and want to use Android SDK's mksdcard tool. Unfortunately it gives me the error, that libgcc_s.so.1 cannot be found, although it is there in my system =>

1.) the error

```
ldd -v /home/user/Android/Sdk/emulator/mksdcard
    linux-gate.so.1 (0xf772b000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => not found
    libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0xf7522000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x565e4000)

    Version information:
    /home/gerd/Android/Sdk/emulator/mksdcard:
            libgcc_s.so.1 (GLIBC_2.0) => not found
            libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.1) => /lib/libc.so.6
            libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.0) => /lib/libc.so.6
    /lib/libc.so.6:
            ld-linux.so.2 (GLIBC_2.3) => /lib/ld-linux.so.2
            ld-linux.so.2 (GLIBC_PRIVATE) => /lib/ld-linux.so.2
            ld-linux.so.2 (GLIBC_2.1) => /lib/ld-linux.so.2
```

2.) check for packages

```
yum list installed | grep libgcc

libgcc.i686                 6.3.1-1.fc25              @updates
libgcc.x86_64               6.3.1-1.fc25              @updates
```

3.) check for library

```
ll /usr/lib*/libgcc_s*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 92872 21. Dez 18:23 /usr/lib64/libgcc_s-6.3.1-20161221.so.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    28 21. Dez 18:19 /usr/lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 -> libgcc_s-6.3.1-20161221.so.1
```

4.) do ldconfig

```
sudo ldconfig -v | grep libgcc
    libgccpp.so.1 -> libgccpp.so.1.0.3
    libgcc_s.so.1 -> libgcc_s-6.3.1-20161221.so.1
```

Although I installed both libgcc .i686 and .x86_64 and 'ldconfig' is listing the library , the error remains.
Since I just find the library under /usr/lib64 I assume the 32-bit version is somehow not properly available.

How to get rid of the error ?
Any help highly appreciated....

Comment: try installing development builds of gcc 'yum -y install glibc-devel.i686 glibc-devel ibstdc++-devel.i686'

Comment: Thanks @xec86 . I installed the packages (incl. typo correction ;) ), executed "ldconfig", but the issue remains.

Comment: 'yum provides libgcc_s.so.1' should give you a list of yum packages that contain that library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @xec86 .
yes, did that already, and it showed:

```
dnf provides libgcc_s.so.1   
Letzte Prüfung auf abgelaufene Metadaten: vor 5:45:26 am Wed Apr 19 11:54:43 2017.
libgcc-6.3.1-1.fc25.i686 : GCC version 6 shared support library
Quelle      : @System

libgcc-6.3.1-1.fc25.i686 : GCC version 6 shared support library
Quelle      : updates

libgcc-6.2.1-2.fc25.i686 : GCC version 6 shared support library
Quelle      : fedora
```

But those were installed already:

```
dnf list installed | grep libgcc
libgcc.i686                              6.3.1-1.fc25              @updates     
libgcc.x86_64                            6.3.1-1.fc25              @updates
```

Just did a reinstallation, this solved the issue:

```
dnf reinstall libgcc.i686
```